# Secure and HttpOnly flags for session cookie Websphere 7

Tags: servlets, cookies, websphere-7, httponly

In Servlet 3.0 complaint application servers I can set the HttpOnly and secure flags for the session cookie (JSESSIONID) by adding the following to the web.xml:

```
<session-config>
  <cookie-config>
    <secure>true</secure>
    <http-only>true</http-only>
  </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

However, the application I'm working on is to be deployed in Websphere 7, which is Servlet 2.5 complaint and it fails to start if I add the above to the web.xml

Is there any other declarative way or setting in Websphere 7 configuration to turn on the HttpOnly and secure flags for the session cookie?

If not, what would be the best approach to accomplish that programmatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think in WebSphere 7 you may have to delve into the administrative console.  As ever the WebSphere documentation seems poor but seems to suggest setting the [com.ibm.ws.security.addHttpOnlyAttributeToCookies](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/usec_seccustomprop.html) property:

> Both the Secure flag and the HTTPOnly flag are enabled by setting the WebSphere Application Server property:
>   `com.ibm.ws.security.addHttpOnlyAttributeToCookies`.

I found [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21422185), which I hope is applicable to WAS7. Can you try please (I only have WAS 8 at the moment on my system):

> ***JSESSIONID cookie:***
>
> **Secure Flag:**
>
> The Secure flag can be set within the WebSphere Application Server
>   administrative interface by selecting AppServer->[Server Name]->Web
>   Container Settings->Session Management.  Check the checkbox for
>   “Restrict cookies to HTTPS Sessions”.
>
> **HTTPOnly Flag:**
>
> The HTTPOnly attribute cannot currently be set on this cookie.  This
>   is registered on the IBM site as APAR PK98436. The fix for this APAR
>   is currently targeted for inclusion in Fix Packs 6.1.0.31 and 7.0.0.9,
>   which are not yet available.  With this APAR in place, the HTTPOnly
>   flag can be set on the JSESSIONID cookie by way of the property name:
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.httpOnlyCookies. Refer to the following
>   technote for instructions on enabling WebContainer custom properties.

The [com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.httpOnlyCookies](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/rweb_custom_props.html) property is documented on the WAS 7 help site.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, my uderstanding from it is that the JSESSIONID (among others) won't be affected by that property. Right?

Comment: Thanks. The second link I think is specific to Tivoli, isn't it? Where did you get the "Both Secure flag and HTTPOnly flag are enabled by ... " quote from ?

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21422185 - Have you tried these solutions?

Answer (score 3):

**To set Secure flag to JSESSIONID cookie (same for WebSphere 7.x and 8.x):**

- log in log in WebSphere admin console
- Navigate to **Server > Server types > WebSphere application servers**
- Click on server name (default is **server1**)
- Click on link **Web Container settings > Web Container**
- Click on link **Session Management**
- Click on link **Enable Cookies**. This bit a litle bit confusing, you have to 
  click on text not on the check box
- select option (check box) **Restrict cookies to HTTPS sessions**
- **Save** changes

---

**To set HttpOnly flag in WebSphere 8.x to JSESSIONID cookie**

- log in log in WebSphere admin console
- Navigate to **Server > Server types > WebSphere application servers**
- Click on server name (default is **server1**)
- Click on link **Web Container settings > Web Container**
- Click on link **Session Management**
- Click on link **Enable Cookies**. This bit a litle bit confusing, you have to click on text not on the check box
- select option (check box) **Set session cookies to HTTPOnly to help prevent cross-site scripting attacks**
- **Save** changes

---

**To set HttpOnly flag in WebSphere 7.x to JSESSIONID cookie**

- log in log in WebSphere admin console
- Navigate to **Server > Server types > WebSphere application servers**
- Click on server name (default is **server1**)
- Click on link **Web Container settings > Web Container**
- Click on link **Custom Proprties**
- Click on button **New**
- Enter **name**: **com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.httpOnlyCookies** **value**:* (HttpOnly will be set on all cookies not only JSESSIONID)
- Click on **OK** button
- **Save** changes

Answer (score 0):

In WebSphere 7, you can find this in the administration console under **Servers** > **WebSphere application servers** > *[Server Name]* > **Session management** (under "Container Settings") > **Enable cookies** > **Restrict cookies to HTTPS sessions**.