# WebSphere Application Server 7 - httpOnly & secure flag for LTPA

Tags: websphere-7, websphere-portal, httponly

I'm working in a common environment having an Apache http-Server in front of the WebSphere Application Server 7 (running a WebSphere Portal Server 7) and now I'm trying to turn on the httpOnly and secure flags for the LTPA cookie.

According to [Secure and HttpOnly flags for session cookie Websphere 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193112/secure-and-httponly-flags-for-session-cookie-websphere-7) and the [support node at IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21422185) I added the custom property
    com.ibm.ws.security.addHttpOnlyAttributeToCookies -> true
inside the WAS7 configuration and restartet the server. The result was that httpOnly flag was set while secure flag wasn't.

Did anyone encounter the same problem and found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, finally I found a (not the) solution. I set the require SSL flag for SSO. This was just mentioned by IBM as standalone solution for the secure flag. How to get there:

Security -> Global Security -> Web- and SIP-Security -> Single Sign-on (SSO) -> check "Requires SSL"

This has been done on IBM WebSphere Application Server 7 with fixpack 7.0.0.27. Maybe the solution from IBM was relying to an older version and they changed the behvaiour in the meanwhile.

Comment: Any idea how to do this using jacl/jython?