# Compatibility Issue with IE10 and IE11

Tags: jsp, internet-explorer, cross-browser, applet, compatibility

I have a website that having some applets, which works without any issues in IE6-IE9. But when I tried in IE10 and IE11, it seems to be buggy. All the pages where not loading properly.

After some searches in google, I found adding the following will solve the problem :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

But even after adding this, my problem was not resolved. When I add the above meta tag, IE's document mode was set to IE9 but the browser mode was still IE10/IE11. If I add my site into compatibility mode it works as good as in IE6-IE9. But whenever the machine accessing the site changes, I need to add the site into compatibility mode.

I would like to know whether I can change code from the server side to solve this compatibility issue of my web site.

My web site's server side uses jsp pages containing some applets and servlet. And the site is deployed in Apache Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be, that IE6-9 do not implement/support all aspects of the java plugin correctly and it migth work there, however not in newer IE's (where it has been fixed.) In that case you should not enable the compatibility mode but fix your applets...

How do other (up-to-date) browsers like chrome (35.X) and firefox (30.X) behave? Does it work?

To give you an example of this you may read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20967173/java-applet-with-form-based-authentication-works-on-ie-fails-on-chrome/20974748#20974748). IE was working but only by violating the spec. Since chrome didn't work and IE did - it seemed that chrome was the problem (which it wasn't).