# Error when deploying application in WebSphere 8.5.5

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I am getting following error message in stdout logs while starting my application in WebSphere 8.5.5

```
SRVE8111E: The application is trying to modify a cookie which matches a pattern in the restricted programmatic session cookies list [domain=*, name=JSESSIONID, path=/].
```

Tried several options like changing cookie name to ‘SOMETHINGELSE’ from ‘JSESSIONID’ while overriding the session settings for war, but see this message not gone away.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193112/secure-and-httponly-flags-for-session-cookie-websphere-7

Comment: What your application is trying to do with session cookie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Explanation** The administrator has disabled changing the cookie configuration for the cookie matching the domain, name, and path.

**Action**  Either modify the application to use a different cookie name, domain, or path or modify the restricted programmatic session cookie values.

You can modify settings from here:

**Servers** > **WebSphere application servers** > **server_name** > **Session management** > **Enable cookies** > **Restrict cookies to HTTPS sessions**.